# Python module installed in site-packages folder, but getting error "No module ..."

Tags: python-3.x, module

Using the Mac Os Terminal, I downloaded the Jupyter lightning module using "pip install lightning-python" in the /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages directory.

However, when I try to import it, I get the error, No module named 'lightning'

and when I list out the files in the site-packages directory, the module doesn't appear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you used pip. pip basically is for version 2 of python. for using it for pip3, you should first install pip3 package. Then copy all your dependencies to python3 libraries.

Hope that answers the question.

Comment: Use **pip** and **pip3** separately to avoid confusion

Comment: But I added the pyglet module using pip?

Comment: While this answer may have worked for the OP, it is incorrect overall. First, there is no such thing as the `pip3` package - you use `pip` for both Python 2 and 3. Additionally, the advice to "copy all your dependencies to python3 libraries" is completely incorrect. Any existing Python 2 packages you want to have available to Python 3 need to be reinstalled, not copied, otherwise they **will not work**.